# Deploying Apache Camel project

Tags: java, maven, deployment, apache-camel

I created a Camel project using spring configuration and now, I need to deploy and run it on my production environment. Basically it's a process that listens to a RabbitMQ broker and, when a message is sent, process it. I'm using eclipse and I create a debug / run configuration with this goal:

```
camel:run
```

Using Spring configuration file to define route and beans, I didn't write any main class, so how can I deploy it and run it? I can't recompile the project on production environment because I cannot install new software so, everything I need to run my process, has to be copied from my development environment.

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html

and

http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

describe mechanisms that allow you to deploy/run.

The camel:run is essentially the same as creating a org.apache.camel.spring.Main class which loads the Spring application context. It can be as simple as :

```
public static void main( final String[] args) {

    Main main = new Main();
    main.setApplicationContextUri("classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
    main.enableHangupSupport();

    try {
        main.run();
    } ...
}
```

This is essentially the same as the camel:run goal.

In order for this to deploy properly, you may need to use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or the [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). This will allow you to create a single artifact (zip, jar, whatever) that can be deployed. Same code, same route definitions.

Comment: cmonkey, thanks! That's the kind of reply I'd like to receive. Short, with reference and a small code sample. Brilliant! Perfect!

Comment: cmonkey, I'm having some trouble whit that process. How can I keep it alive for ever? (until I manually kill it). I removed enableHangupSupport() and now it remains alive for 40 / 50 minutes but, after that it will closed. With enableHangupSupport() it remains alive 4 minutes at least.

Comment: The process described *should* keep it alive forever. I presume that some sufficiently fatal exception is being thrown in application code. Or, some code is destroying the application context. Any logs? Stderr? Might merit a new question depending on the problem.

Comment: Now it's working fine. Not sure what changed (and I'm really worried about it). Or better, I used same application context to access database on processor. Now I splitted it, one application context for Camel and one for DB, may be the processor destroyed the application context at the end of execution.